# Magento, trouble with getting product collection by manufacturer

Tags: magento, collections, attributes

Good afternoon!

I am a beginner in magento, so have a question connected with getting product collection by manufacturer.

The code I used is bellow:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');
        $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
            array('attribute' => 'manufacturer', 'eq' =>'adidas'),
        ));

        return $collection;
```

I checked that products with such attribute and value exist, but the size of returned array is 0.

Maybe, I have missed something important with attribute options or something else.

So I will be very thankful for every advice or idea.

Answer (score 0):

If manufacturer dropdown value id is 10 then you can filter like this

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
 $collection->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer',10);
 return $collection;
```